# Can you provide scala view bounds from Java?

Tags: java, scala

Suppose I have

```
val a: Option[String] = None
someJavaFunction(a)
```

And then in the java file, I want to do something like this:

```
public someJavaFunction(Option<String> o) {
  o.orNull();
}
```

The signature of orNull, however, is this:

```
orNull [A1 >: A](implicit ev : <:<[Null, A1]) : A1
```

So from Java, I'd need to supply this evidence function that is usually magicked in by Scala (from I know not where). How might I get hold of the evidence value to pass in here?

This is clearly not sensible.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808821/java-calling-scala-case-class-w-implicit-parameter

Comment: A possibly could be to simply pass `null`, but that doesn't seem very clean. `o.orNull(null)`.

Comment: @user3707125 Thanks for the pointer. I know how to pass the parameter - the question is, what do I pass in?

Comment: @Clashsoft Good idea - unfortunately, that results in an NPE, looks like the implementation of orNull is using the evidence parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<:<` class is defined in `scala.Predef` and normally it's `scala.Predef.conforms()` that gives you an instance in Scala. So you could do something like

```
public class Foo {
  public static String foo(scala.Option<String> o) {
    return o.orNull(
      (scala.Predef.$less$colon$less< scala.runtime.Null$ , String >)
      (Object)scala.Predef.conforms()
    );
  }
}
```

which gives an unchecked operation warning, but works.

You can also create an instance of `scala.Predef.$less$colon$less` that does the right thing (just returns its argument), and there the cast goes through without warning.

Note: you must leave a space after `Null$` or javac gets confused.